# How to get without using the return statement class inside function variable value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is my code.I can not even use the database.

I need get without using the return statement class inside function variable values.

```py
class Hello:
    def alex_details():
        name = "Hello"
        last_nem = "World"

    def liam_details():
        name = "Hello"
        last_name = "World"


hi = Hello()

print(hi.alex_details.name)
```

erorr:

```sh
print(hi.alex_details.name)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, but at the moment, you only have local variables in the two functions. What's the reason for avoiding return statements?

Comment: If you want the namespace use a nested class.

Comment: I want use its different functions and class

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code can help your problem.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "default name"
        self.last_name = "default last name"

    def alex_details(self):
        self.name = "alex"
        self.last_name = "sandra"

    def liam_details(self):
        self.name = "liam"
        self.last_name = "World"


hi = Hello()
print(hi.name) #output: "default name"
hi.alex_details()
print(hi.name) #output: "alex"
hi.liam_details()
print(hi.name) #output: "liam"
```